# Change the server URL with tabris iOS client?

Tags: ios, eclipse, tabris

it is possible to change the server URL of the Tabris iOS Client in an other way like hardcoded it in XCode in the AppDelegate.m file ?

The Tabris Android client allows directly to change the URL in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically it is possible.
You would need to add that functionality to your native iOS client (e.g. using the iOS settings).

We do not include this functionality in the minimal iOS client project template for Xcode for two reasons:

1. It would not be a nice user experience to have the user change a URL in a "native" app to access different functionality. Therefor I would recommend to create multiple Apps - one for each server/URL/usecase.
2. If you want to provide your app in the Apple AppStore, Apple does not allow to completely change the described app behavior - which would be possible by just changing the URL.

If you intend to release the App for your Enterprise (and not in the App Store), you can integrate this functionality. (We have done this for our internal development client - this eases development against different servers with just one App)